# Removed debug.log, and it is not generating again

Tags: rhel, logs, syslog

Using RHEL 7.2, due to larger file size I've removed debug.log (from /var/log/debug.log). And after that debug.log file is not generating automatically.
I've checked "messages" log it's working fine.

Comment: check if it's enabled in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. also, restart `rsyslog` if you have it installed on the system.

Comment: Whatever processes are writing to it may still have the file opened for writing (and are therefore writing to a file without a name in the filesystem). Rebooting is a bit heavy-handed, but should solve that issue.

Comment: Cool..! restarting rsyslog worked. Thanks!